# Delete method of range failed vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 columns, I am doing a comparison on each cell of the column A and B with row count of 1613 to check if it does not contain a select number of strings.  I then try and delete the row if it doesnt contain either of the strings however I have come across an error `Delete method of Range class failed`  However I am not sure what is wrong

```
Sub macro()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set xSheet = Worksheets("RAW DATA (2)")
xSheet.Select
For i = 1 To 1613
    If InStr(Cells(i, 2).Value, "Error") = False Or InStr(Cells(i, 2).Value, "No credentials") = False Or InStr(Cells(i, 2).Value, "Connection Failed") = False Then
        xSheet.Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that the sheet may be protected. So, check it again and say me, it is protected or not.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you're close!  Just add the "EntireRow" qualifier (I have no idea if that's the right term for that) to that line: `xSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete`.

Comment: I just tried that however I still got the same error

Comment: Really? It worked for me, hmm.... If you walk through the macro (press F8), does it still show you the same error on that line?

Comment: Is the Sub in the worksheet, or a new module? I Don't think it matters though...hm.